# Add/Edit Google Calendar of arbitrary Google Account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I got a google sheet with a script. How do I **create a google calendar** of a specific google account (not the one that currently uses the sheet, but one I own), **add/update events**, **get the sharing link of that calendar** and **add the sharing link** to  said google sheet?

Background: My Google sheet is shared with quite a few users that edit it. The table defines events (actually a night shift roster) that are assigned to different people. I want to create individual calendars and share it with those people so they see in their calendar, when they have night shifts. Via that sharing link they might also be able to add the calendar to ical/outlook/their gmail calendar.

BTW: I had a look at the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/), however it seems you can only edit a calendar of the user currently using the sheet.

Comment: Did I describe it uncomprehensively?

Comment: You can't edit someone else's information unless you have been given that access. Thus, arbitrary account manipulation is impossible. You must have a defined relationship with any account to be edited, i.e., they have given you access explicitly, or are in a domain to which you have been delegated authority.

Comment: You can, of course, create resources for your account and share them with whomever you like, giving them whatever access you like, to the resources you own. (Subject of course to your domain's privacy / sharing restrictions.)

Comment: Sure, thing is this: I have full access of the account where I want to acess/edit the calendars. Usecase however is, that the people I share the sheet with edit it - as a result - i want to edit the calendars of my other account where I have access to.

Comment: So its not the calendars of the user currently using the sheet but of a separate account that is owned by me.

Comment: Use an installed trigger or a backend web app that executes as you

Comment: You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011467/google-apps-script-create-calendar-event-from-sheet-forbidden) wherein you can try to abstract the calendar event creation function away from your Spreadsheet bound script to a separate standalone apps-script that runs under your name with your permissions. You can also check the [Advanced Calendar Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) documentation then enable the Advance Google Services to allow the collaborator to gain access in your organization.